# delete or virtual delete?

Tags: c++, virtual

I am writing a lib and a demo project. The project doesn't care which version of the lib I use (I can use sdl, directx or whatever I like as the gfx backend). To get the object I do

```
Obj *obj = libname_newDevice();
```

Now, should I use delete or should I do `obj->deleteMe();`? I ask because I am not exactly doing new so I shouldn't be doing the delete?

I have `obj->create(theType);` which returns a class with the Obj interface.
My real question is do I need a `libname_deleteDevice();` or is `obj->deleteMe()` fine since I have a deleteMe in the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take one step further.
If you are using a factory function to create, it may be logical to use a factory function to destroy. In addition to this to make it all nice and exetion safe wrap in in an object.

```
class ObjWrap
{
    public:
        ObjWrap()
            :obj(libname_newDevice())
        {}
        ~ObjWrap()
        {    libname_deleteDevice(obj);}
    private:
        ObjWrap(ObjWrap const&);        // Dont copy
        void operator=(ObjWrap const&); // Dont copy
        Obj* obj;
}; // If you want to copy then you need to extra work on ref counting
   // This may need some form of smart pointer.
```

Answer (score 11):

Since you are abstracting the creation inside `libname_newDevice()` (which I have to say isn't a good approach), you should destroy using something like `libname_destroyDevice (obj)`.

And as the comment from Martin suggests, it's best to put them in the constructor and destructor of a custom class, that you just need to create on stack, and the compiler will take care of the rest.

Comment: Yes, symmetry is nice. Then you should wrap the whole thing inside an object where these two functions are called by the constructor/destructor.

Answer (score 4):

Please try to clarify your question. It's totally unclear to me.

- Why do you speak of a graphical back end? Is it relevant to the question?
- Are you asking how you should design your library or how you should use it?

It's good practice to have an object factory to create the object. I assume this is the role of `libname_newDevice()`.

The library should also provide a way to delete the object (such as `obj->DeleteMe()` or `libname_Delete(obj)` ).

Don't rely on C++'s `delete`: caller and library might have been compiled with different version of the compiler, which would do different things regarding memory and resources allocation. It's therefore safer if your lib deletes the object it created.

Comment: I gues graphics is not relevant. Specifically i want to know if i should do libname_Delete() or if i should do obj->DeleteMe(); I also have a obj->create(theType);

Comment: It is safer (in Windows) if the lib deletes objects it creates. But your reasoning for why is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to honor [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and have some reference counting wrapper object (you can even use [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) with a custom deallocator).

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to implement Obj::deleteMe(). It would have to do something like:

```
delete this;
```

while you were still inside this->deleteMe(). Follow Jaywalker's suggestion and make the destroy function take an Obj* as a parameter.

Comment: "delete this;" may make ones skin crawl, but it isn't necessarily bad. Objects which implement their own reference counting always have to do this. For examples, see Release() in every "my first COM implementation".